# Understanding CSS line-height

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, safari, wkwebview

Why is the line height different between these two paragraphs (at least in Safari and Chrome on OS X)? Shouldn't the default line height be 1.0, which I would interpret as the "natural" height of a given font (where descenders on the line above do not touch ascenders from the line below)? I find that if I use 1.0, descenders get cut off by the line below (depending on the font).

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/craig9999/774L2w82/)

```
<p style="font:14pt/1.0 Times">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque maximus mi vel erat finibus, eu tincidunt vehicula quis eu odio. In vel nisi non odio consequat porta in eros, sit amet tincidunt nunc dictum eu. In rhoncus convallis dapibus.</p>
<p style="font:14pt Times">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque maximus mi vel erat finibus, eu tincidunt vehicula quis eu odio. In vel nisi non odio consequat porta in eros, sit amet tincidunt nunc dictum eu. In rhoncus convallis dapibus.</p>
```

I have an HTML "web view" embedded in my iOS app and want to give the user control over line spacing. I find I need to use something like 1.2, 1.8, and 2.4 for single, one-and-a-half, and double spacing. Anything less than about 1.2 and the lines overlap.

I've found other questions where 1.2 is described as equivalent to `normal`, which looks about right.

So second question is, how can I calculate at run time (assuming it might vary by device) the fudge factor that I need to multiply line spacing by so that lines don't overlap? Or is 1.2 a "rule" that I can assume will always be true?

Comment: Natural line height is a font property. Could be different for different fonts.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It turns out that setting the `line-height` to 1.0 means "slightly overlap the line above when writing each line". In order to avoid this, every Web designer in the world has to make adjustments to `line-height` to guess at what every browser in the world is going to do, instead of a small number of browser writers making their software work correctly in the first place.

**EDIT**: Further research has revealed if you create a `UIFont` using the selected font family and size, you can get the exact line height multiplier to use by dividing the `UIFont` `lineHeight` property by the `pointSize` property. This doesn't do you much good on a website, but it works great when you have an integrated web view as described in the question.

Comment: Downvote all you want. This is the correct answer. When you use 1.0, your browser uses a line height that is shorter than the actual height of the font. You have to guess what magic value means "1.0" in each browser and use that instead. This is the precisely correct answer to the first part of my question, and implies the answer to the second part; that is, yes, you need to examine the line height used by each browser to calculate what to use when you mean 1.0. Because this answer is correct, I selected it as correct. This is stackoverflow at its best, not a bad answer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe its actually due to the font. Font families can have different line heights based on their chars. The default for Times is not equal to the default sans-serif (browser default).

> **normal**
>       Depends on the user agent. Desktop browsers (including Firefox) use a default value of roughly 1.2, depending on the element's *font-family.* [mdn link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height)

Comment: Which is exactly why one would want to just say "1.0" and expect to get the natural line height of the font. One would expect that single-spacing would not cause descenders and ascenders to collide. In fact, I would expect that 1.0 is the smallest `line-height` I could use that would guarantee that the user agent wouldn't overlap the lines. Instead, it appears that something around 1.2 is how some (?) user agents keep lines from colliding. I suspect this has something to do with making 1.0 be equal to the point size, which is not the same as the height of the font.

Comment: It's as if we've taken a bad interpretation of `line-height` and baked it into every user agent. I can understand that `normal` could be something other than 1.0, but I don't understand why 1.0 would mean "draw the line in such a way that it overlaps the line above.